# AngularJS + Asp.net WebApi - Cannot get authentication to work due to CORS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, cors

I have an AngularJS app which talks to an ASP.Net WebApi backend.

Both the UI and the API are hosted on the same domain/server, but on different ports:

- UI: https://www.example.com
- API: https://www.example.com:8888

The UI is successfully communicating with the API for all required HTTP Methods (GET, POST, etc.), but I cannot get authentication to work.

When the call to "/login" is made, I get the following response from the API:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.example.com:8888/api/login' from origin 'https://www.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

#### Excerpt of Web.Config from ASP.Net WebApi

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    ...
    <httpProtocol>
       ...
       <customHeaders>
         <clear />
            <!-- CORS Configuration -->
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="https://www.example.com" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
            <!-- /CORS Configuration -->
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

- There is no other CORS-related configuration within the API app.

#### Call to authenticate from AngularJS front-end

```
attemptLogin (userId, password) {
  var data = {
    UserId: userId,
    Password: password
  };
     
  return this.$http.post("https://www.example.com:8888/login", data, { withCredentials: true });       
}
```

#### Interestingly...

... if I set the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header to wildcard "*", I get a different message, which would indicate that the API is correctly identifying the API call as relating to authentication.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.example.com:8888/api/login' from origin 'https://www.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Can anyone shed any light on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

You might need to include the port you're using on UI. Like this:

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="https://www.example.com:4200" />
```